Vyper: how to import structs from a module in vyper
I'm trying to write a smart contract in vyper, and I have 2 files, one of which will be used as module, by composition in the other.
So lets say the first file is A.vy
struct MyResult:
    initialValue: int256
    finalResult: int256


# Initialization functions and stuff...

@internal
def updateAndGetValues(sumArg: int256) -> MyResult:
    result: MyResult = empty(MyResult)
    # Do something and return MyResul
    return result

@internal
def saveValues(someArg: MyResult)
    pass# does somethings


and then in a second file (lets call it extended.vy I want to use both the functionality and the struct. How should I do this?
import A

# some functions

def validateValues(uses: int256):
    # How should I use the MyResult struct?
    result: MyResult = self.A.updateAndGetValues(uses)
    assert result.initialValue < uses
    result.finalResult += 1
    self.a.saveValues(result)

This code will not compile!
I can't find A way to reference the struct from another file.
This is an issue that seems to be solved in the Vyper repo, by this PR But I can't seem to make it work in any way.
I've also tried to redefine the struct and it does not work.
p.s.
I'm using vyper version 0.4.0

You can simply use A.MyResult from extended.vy. For example, the following compiles:
import A

# some functions

def validateValues(uses: int256):
    result: A.MyResult = A.updateAndGetValues(uses)
    assert result.initialValue < uses
    result.finalResult += 1
    A.saveValues(result)

